# Android SQLite Database(3300): sqlite returned: error code = 1

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm starting to go a little mad ha ha, I have spent two days trying to fix this error below, could someone please help me as I can't work it out :(

//DB Adapter class to create the table

```
public class DBAdapter {

    private static final String vd_offer = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VD_OFFER  + " ("
                + OFFER_ID + " INTEGER, " // PRIMARY KEY
                + VENUE_ID + " INTEGER, " 
                + OFFER_COST + " INTEGER, " 
                + OFFER_NAME + " TEXT, " 
                + OFFER_DESC_SHORT + " TEXT, " 
                + OFFER_DESC_LONG + " TEXT, " 
                + OFFER_DATE_START + " TEXT, " 
                + OFFER_DATE_END + " TEXT, " 
                + OFFER_RECUR + " TEXT );"
                );

    private final Context context; 
    private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;


    public DBAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        this.DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
        {
            db.execSQL(vd_offer); 
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
        int newVersion) 
        {               
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VD_OFFER);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    } 

    public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        this.db = this.DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() 
    {
        this.DBHelper.close();
    }
}
```

// Class to pass vaiables to DB

```
public class VDOffer {

    private DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb;

    private final Context mCtx;

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        }
    }


    public VDOffer(Context ctx) {
        this.mCtx = ctx;
    }

    public VDOffer open() throws SQLException {
        this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this.mCtx);
        this.mDb = this.mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public void close() {
        this.mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public long addOffer (int offer_id, int venue_id, int offer_cost, 
            String offer_name, String offer_desc_short, String offer_desc_long,
            String offer_date_start, String offer_date_end, String offer_recur){

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        values.put(OFFER_ID, offer_id);
        values.put(VENUE_ID, venue_id);
        values.put(OFFER_COST, offer_cost);
        values.put(OFFER_NAME, offer_name);
        values.put(OFFER_DESC_SHORT, offer_desc_short);
        values.put(OFFER_DESC_LONG, offer_desc_long);
        values.put(OFFER_DATE_START, offer_date_start);
        values.put(OFFER_DATE_END, offer_date_end);
        values.put(OFFER_RECUR, offer_recur);       

        return this.mDb.insert(TABLE_VD_OFFER, null, values);

    }
}
```

// Just some code hacked together to test the input

```
public void update (){

    int offer_id = 1;
    int venue_id = 1;
    int offer_cost = 1;
    String offer_name = "test";
    String offer_desc_short = "test";
    String offer_desc_long = "test";
    String offer_date_start = "test";
    String offer_date_end = "test";
    String offer_recur = "test";        

    VDOffer entry = new VDOffer(Events.this);

    boolean didItWork = true;
    try {
        entry.open();
        entry.addOffer(offer_id, venue_id, offer_cost, offer_name, offer_desc_short, offer_desc_long, offer_date_start, offer_date_end, offer_recur);
        entry.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        didItWork = false;
        String error = e.toString();
        Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
        d.setTitle("Dang it!");
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText(error);
        d.setContentView(tv);
        d.show();
    } finally {
        if (didItWork) {
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Heck Yea!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("Success");
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();
            entry.close();
        }
    }
```

}

// Logs Cat

```
05-29 23:56:43.021: W/KeyCharacterMap(30728): No keyboard for id 0
05-29 23:56:43.021: W/KeyCharacterMap(30728): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-29 23:56:47.960: D/dalvikvm(30728): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1925 objects / 139800 bytes in 362ms
05-29 23:56:49.840: I/Database(30728): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such table: vd_offer
05-29 23:56:49.850: E/Database(30728): Error inserting offer_desc_long=test offer_desc=test offer_date_end=test offer_id=1 offer_recur=test offer_name=test venue_id=1 offer_date_start=test offer_cost=1
05-29 23:56:49.850: E/Database(30728): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: vd_offer: , while compiling: INSERT INTO vd_offer(offer_desc_long, offer_desc, offer_date_end, offer_id, offer_recur, offer_name, venue_id, offer_date_start, offer_cost) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);
```

Comment: Maybe I'm alittle tired, but you are trying to store some values in ONE database right?

Comment: Have you declared TABLE_VD_OFFER from the SQLiteException is stating that Table in which you are trying to add values does not exist.Have you done something like private static final String TABLE_VD_OFFER = "vd_offer_table"; ?

Comment: Yea trying to create a DB and then a table within it and then add some values to that table. Later on I want to be able to add more tables, so I have done it like this to make it easier in the long run. I really have no clue what I'm doing wrong, as far as everything I have read I'm doing it correct!

Comment: @Viking I have declared it in another class like so:

public static final String TABLE_VD_OFFER = "vd_offer";

and call it like this: import static com.test.sqlite.Constents.TABLE_VD_OFFER;

Comment: @James Ok, I see your point. But I still can see how this implementation will work. When you initialize `VDOffer entry` and call `entry.open()`, the DatabaseHelper inside VDOffer will try to open a database. Put that DatabaseHelper does not have any CREATE statement in onCreate().

Answer (score 1):

You have two(!!!) classes called `DatabaseHelper` and only one of them has the code to create your table.  You need to lose the one without the table creation code and make sure you point to the other one to create your database.

**EDIT**

You should have all DB activities in your dbhelper class, then instantiate that and use it when you need to.  Get rid of the `DatabaseHelper` class in @`vdOffer` and use this:

```
private DBAdapter mDbhelper;
mDbHelper = new DBAdapter(this);
mDbHelper.open();
```

And then create insert methods in there and access them.

```
mDbHelper.insertOffer(parameters);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to comment I appreciate it! I have tried that but it doesn't like it when I remove it from vdoffer class so I have to keep it.